# Trying to embed a TextField or TextFormField within a BottomAppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, android-bottomappbar, bottomappbar

I'm trying to build a BottomAppBar which contains a few icons (two on the left and another two on the right), and I'd like to add a Text input field in between them but whatever I try, it doesn't work.

Code compiles fine but when opening the page which uses this widget, the following error now appears:

**RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#bcb66 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT**

Here's my code:

```
Widget _buildBottomNavBar(){
  return BottomAppBar(
    child: Row(
      children:
      [
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file_rounded), onPressed: () {}),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined), onPressed: () {}),
        TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Message'),
        ),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow_rounded), onPressed: () {}),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.undo_rounded), onPressed: () {}),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

This seems simple but I've tried multiple things (including wrapping the TextFormField in an Expanded widget) but nothing seems to work.  Any useful ideas are much appreciated.  tia

**UPDATE (here's the fixed code, forgot to add child:)**

```
Widget _buildBottomNavBar(){
  return BottomAppBar(
    child: Row(
      children:
      [
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file_rounded), onPressed: () {}),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined), onPressed: () {}),
        Expanded(child:
        TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Message'),
        )),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow_rounded), onPressed: () {}),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.undo_rounded), onPressed: () {}),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Btw pardon my crappy indentation.

Comment: I had no problem with this after wrapping `TextFormField` in an `Expanded` widget. I believe your problem lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Where you put this code ? If is it Column or Row you should wrap it with Sizedbox or something like that. I had no problem with that.

Comment: @Onur, I'm calling it within a Column context.

Comment: I think there is a problem at your column. Can you share it

Comment: @Onur:  Here's the relevant bit of the Column code:

    Widget _chatForm() {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[

Comment: you can just remove Row which is inside `_buildBottomNavBar` and Create Stack with same items

Comment: I got it working, sorry it was a stupid typo.  I'll delete this post soon so as not to waste anyone else's time.  Thanks all.

Comment: @theiskaa, I thought Stack was only to be used if you want to layer widgets on top of each other, which I'm not trying to do here.

Comment: No no wait i have solved it

Comment: I will push answer just one min give me one minute pls